# Почему не работает draggable библиотеки Jqueryui на вновь созданном элементе?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

создаю

```
var date = new Date();
                var path =  '/frontend/web/image/frontendImage/carusel/'+date.getFullYear()+'/'+(1+date.getMonth())+'/avatar-'+file.name;
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = path; 
                img.setAttribute('class','draggable ui-widget-content');
                document.getElementById('forIMG').appendChild(img);}
```

подключаю

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
    $("#forIMG").on('draggable','.draggable');
```

но ни так ни так не работает не подскажите как правильно

Comment: `$("#forIMG").on('draggable', function(){
     $(".draggable").draggable();
});`

Comment: и классы не забывай ui-widget-content draggable

Comment: классы не  забыл вот  `img.setAttribute('class','draggable ui-widget-content');`. Но Ваш код не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так сработало

```
$("#forIMG").on('mousedown', function(){ $(".draggable").draggable(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".draggable").draggable()` нужно инициализировать уже после загрузки DOM,
в Вашем случае `$("#forIMG").on('mousedown', function(){ $(".draggable").draggable(); });`инициализирует draggable() после загрузки по нажатию кнопки мыши. Либо оставить как есть, либо искать - в каком месте он у Вас подключается.